# How do you find the number of times a rectangle can fit inside another rectangle?

Tags: java

I'm a making a retro-style game in Java with a set 256*192 resolution and I want to scale the game by an even number based on how many times the player's resizable window can fit that resolution inside it.

For example, if the window is default 256*192, the scale is 1.
If the window is 512*384, the scale is 2.
But if the window resolution is a different aspect ratio, such as 560*490, the maximum number of times the original resolution can fit is still 3, so the scale would be 3 and I'd just fill the extra bounds with black or some basic pattern.

Maybe it's a stupidly simple answer and I just haven't had enough coffee yet, but I can't figure out how to find the number for scale.
Help?

Answer (score 3):

Say your game is `a*b` and the window is `x*y`. You can find the proportionally greater dimension of the window by comparing `x/a` to `y/b`. Your scale should be whichever of  those two values is smaller. If you want it to be an integer, just round down whichever value is smaller.